# Remove Alert box before it pops up

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I am trying to remove an Alert box on an external site with Grease Monkey and jQuery.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>alert("Remove this Alert box with GreaseMonkey.");</script>

<p>Hello world</p>

</body>
</html>
```

GreaseMonkey script (currently without the jQuery part):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Remove Alert box
// @include     http://www.example.com/alert_remove/
// ==/UserScript==

var node = document.getElementsByTagName('alert');
node.parentNode.removeChild(node);

if(window.alert) {
    alert("ALERT DETECTED");  // No response.
}
```

I don't think this can be solved using jQuery since the jQuery code only triggers when the page has loaded and the alert is visible ($(document).ready).

Can I remove the alert-element from the DOM?
Can I send a keypress (13=Enter) to handle the alert if it shows up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Greasemonkey is loaded after the page and the script isn't triggered by any event, I think it's impossible to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Greasemonkey doesn't run until the page is loaded, so this is not possible with Greasemonkey. If you are really determined, you could set up a proxy (such as [squid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_%28software%29)) with a method similar to what is used in this [Upside-Down-Ternet](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/upside-down-ternet.html) trick.

If you can get your own JavaScript to run before the other code calls `alert`, then you would want to do something like this:

```
window.backupAlert = window.alert;
window.alert = function () {return true};
```

(tested working)

You can then use the `backupAlert` function in place of `alert` in your own scripts, but other scripts that assume `alert` still exists will not show a popup.

The reasoning for this is that alert is a **function** inside the window object; it is not a tag or DOM object in the document.

And no, you cannot send a keypress with JavaScript. This is globally true; you can trigger the functions that handle key press events, but you can't send OS click or keypress events.

Comment: Interesting solution. How about simply sending a keypress (Enter) when the Alert pops up? It can be done with AutoHotkey, but with JavaScript?

Comment: No, unfortunately there is no keypress sending mechanism. You can detect keypresses and handle them, and you can trigger the keypress handlers that you define, but there's no way to imitate a keypress event outside of the web page (including in the alert window, in other areas of the browser, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

> var node = document.getElementsByTagName('alert');
>   node.parentNode.removeChild(node);

- it won't work at all, cause "alert" is not a node, but "script" is. If you managed to execute your GreaseMonkey script before alert was shown, you have to do this instead:

> var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
>   var str = node.firstChild.textContent;
>   var result = str.replace(/alert("[\w\s.]*");/, "");
>   node.firstChild.textContent = result;

- tested in FireFox. What is going on there - you look for first script tag (can be easy done to look all of them), then you take its content (code), then you replace alert with empty string and put modifide code back. In your case result page will still heve script tag, but without any code;

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of doing it with javascript, since js runs on a rendered page already.  My first thoughts would be to catch it before the page renders.  Like with PHP.  Read the contents of the external site into a string and the strip out the ALERT lines of code, then display the page.