# Dismiss leave page dialogs automatically using Chromedriver (Codeception)

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, codeception

I have written a series of acceptance tests that work when executed independently. I am using ChromeDriver to carry out this tests with Codeception.

However, when I run all the procedures from a test class I get a dialog about

`This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved.`

This is a browser modal alert, hence all the tests that follow fail as the browser cannot navigate away from this page.

Is there an way in Codeception or Chromedriver to accept the dialog with default keys so that other tests can be performed sequentially? Or to tell Codeception to force close the current window and try a new window?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing with settings for a while, the only way to get passed is to set the `restart` property to true (false by default):

```
        WebDriver:
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/'
            wait: 2
            window_size: false # disabled in ChromeDriver
            port: 9515
            browser: chrome
            restart: true
```

This will close the browser window and the dialog will not be displayed.  A new browser will be opened for the next test.

This solution will make the acceptance run tests even slow, so I'm keen to see if anyone else has a better solution!

Worth noting that I tried playing with the `unexpectedAlertBehaviour`  [capability](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities) and no matter what value I have it, the alert would not be dismissed.

Answer (score 1):

I found similar question for different test framework: [Prevent onbeforeunload dialog from interfering with tests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47683072/366348)

Proposed solution is to execute `window.onbeforeunload = undefined;` after each page load.

With Codeception you have to use `executeJS` method:

```
$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->executeJS('window.onbeforeunload = undefined;');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the executeJS code after the page loaded and the dialog keeps showing up (video URL at end). I checked the console log and no errors were shown. This is a PITA to troubleshoot. https://dsc.cloud/6946fd/Screen-Recording-2021-01-02-15-32-25-1609561958.mp4

Comment: Probably you have to add a short wait period after amOnPage to delay execution of javascript until the page is completely loaded. Please review available methods at https://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#wait

Comment: Thanks again for your feedback, the waiting did not make a difference, but did find a way to overcome this via WebDriver properties, please check it out below.

Answer (score 0):

You could inject jQuery to delete the confirmation box, I believe. (Disclaimer: Not a website coder).

**Edit: I don't think that's viable.**

See [Remove Alert box before it pops up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374797/remove-alert-box-before-it-pops-up)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not an dialog created by the web application, the dialog is created at the browser level so jQuery cannot interact with it (AFAIK).